# Hornet Zapper power board recommendation

Tags: power-supply, pcb

I'm building a device to supply some hornet trap and would like some advice regarding the components I choosed:

With the aim of reducing hornet pressure on bees colony, I am working on a board powered from 12 V solar panel to supply high voltage board .

I'd appreciatre comments on my design - perhaps other solutions to achieve it (cheaper or more efficiently,) and any advice or recommendation to enhance it.

The voltage booster looks like this  - (4.2 V -> 2000 V output):

[image: 2000v boost board]

I have little knowledge in electronics.  Here is what I've designed so far:

1. Reverse voltage protection

[image: reverse voltage protection]

2. Buck-boost regulator 10 V from L5973D013TR chip to control MOSFET and NE555:

[image: 10v regulator]

3. Boyce-boost regulator 4.2 V from L5973D013TR chip to supply high voltage board at is maximum power:

[image: 4.2v regulator]

4. NE555 chip to protect and enhanced reliability of the high voltage board, also add a port to handle rain sensor.

[image: NE555]

5. Here is the full PCB:

[image: pcb]

The high voltage board consumes around 200 mA and I will have a maximum of 8 devices on a power supply board.

Comment: It will probably help your question if you place the question near the top, and mke it  mor d3efinite question.  ~~~~= " I am building a xxx. I would like advice on ....". People here tend to close questions that they perecive to not be questions - even if they are. || I've edited the question. Please amend my edits as desired,.

Comment: Please don't draw schematics by labelling the pins of a chip and expecting someone to try and mentally link those pins with labels on the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Minor point: [L5973D](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/4e/55/f1/3b/07/ef/4e/02/CD00002851.pdf/files/CD00002851.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00002851.pdf) is buck only. Which is how you are using it here.

Comment: @Andyaka  What would "more focused" look like in this case in your opinion? || He's saying "This is my design. Is it OK?". How would he put that more succinctly?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I don't think I voted to close on it being not focussed. I believe (and I could be wrong) that I voted to close on clarity reasons. But, as you know, only one reason is given above.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Ok thanks! I've edited it regarding you're recommendation. But in the figure 17 of the exact datasheet you linked to [L5973D](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/4e/55/f1/3b/07/ef/4e/02/CD00002851.pdf/files/CD00002851.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00002851.pdf) it's said Buck-boost regulator?

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry for the wiring labelling but the wiring is strictly what's provide by datasheet, i'm more looking for advice on the components choosed and global harmony of the board, I'll try to update it with full wire anyway, thanks.

Comment: @AlexisGekiere  Correct - Well found ! :-). The IC is designed and described as a step down switching regulator. || The application note designer managed to use the IC in ways not strictly in accordance with its original design. || Fig 17 is a NEGATIVE output buck-boost (note the negative sign in "VOUT=**-**12V...". This is a classic inverting buck boost. || Fig 16 is a positive to positive buck-boost - and I'd want to test it to see if it's cleverness works properly in practice :-).  FET M1 and L1 is an added pure boost circuit fed by the buck only IC stage. Quite clever. Must try :-).